# How to limit number of div classes looped and returned?

Tags: html, xpath

I am using XPath to grab information from html webpages but want to limit the information to the first 5 divs on the page. So I only want Info 1, Info 2, Info 3, Info 4 and Info 5 from the page below. I tried this but it doesn't seem to do the job:

```
(//div[@class='loop')[position() <= 5]
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="loop">Info 1</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 2</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 3</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 4</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 5</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 6</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 7</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 8</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 9</div>
    <div class="loop">Info 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. This should do the trick:

```
//div[@class='loop' and position() <= 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only missing the `]` on your first predicate (directly after `'loop'`)...

```
(//div[@class='loop'])[position() <= 5]
```